# Linux software for periodical work break

Tags: linux, software-rec, centos, rsi

I am using Cent OS 5. 
I am looking for an app which will alert me after some time to take break. So I can use computer as healthy computer usages ?

Comment: There are many things that can do something like this, from **cron** to **at** if you want something that runs from the console. There are also many calendar and "reminder" apps--if that's what you want, you probably want one that's intended for use with your desktop environment of choice.

Comment: @ Flimzy
I am looking for a Gui Application like Timeout for MAC.

Comment: The developer community really needs more work break application usage! Thank you for asking this instead off me, now every 1 h will be tee time for me. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

the best choice for you would be probably [Workrave](http://www.workrave.org/)

[image: Workrave settings]

Comment: I really like workrave. It also shows you some helpful exercises to perform during the rest breaks.

Comment: Does not work in ubuntu 13.04.  Also this screen shot is for windows xp

Comment: just installed in latest Kubuntu and seems to work without problem. And the program GUI looks almost the same way as in Win XP.

Comment: After I updated my system workrave stopped working, after about 2 minutes, the graphics disappears and you can still see the process running, but it is does not break anymore.  The code may not work with the latest kernel.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two more alternatives that haven't been mentioned in the other answers.

[**Xwrits**](http://www.lcdf.org/xwrits/):

> Xwrits reminds you to take wrist
>   breaks, which will hopefully help you
>   prevent repetitive stress injury. It
>   pops up an X window when you should
>   rest; you click on that window, then
>   take a break.

[**RSIBreak**](http://www.rsibreak.org/):

> Repetitive Strain Injury can occur as
>   a result of working with a mouse and
>   keyboard. This utility can be used to
>   remind you to take a break now and
>   then. It displays a random picture
>   from a collection at specified
>   intervals for defined durations. You
>   can configure the pictures to show and
>   lengths of time to show them. You
>   might use the breaks reminders to do
>   some stretching exercises, for
>   example, or as a reminder to walk away
>   from the computer for a while.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04 -> RSIBreak  it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with using a "web app", [Evo](http://www.protectyourvision.org) will do. May not be idea for several situations, but if you spend a good deal of time in a web browser, it should fit just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Project Hamster](http://projecthamster.wordpress.com/)?

Lifehacker had it as one of their top five time management programs.

Comment: Does this program really provide *alerts* for taking breaks?

Comment: not sure, it read like it does, but I might have misread.

Comment: For external links, which can often change, it is good to summarize their contents, and explain their relevance to the question. You merely say that someone says that it is a "top five time management programs". This question is not about time management.